# How can I pin murder on Eli, the pedophile?

Tags: la-noire

I'm playing "The Golden Butterfly", the second mission in L.A. Noire's Homicide chapter.

Diedre Moller has been murdered.  There are two suspects in the case, her husband, Hugo, and a pedophile, Eli.

I've found all 12 clues in the case, and I'm back at Central where I have the opportunity to interrogate both suspects.  I've gotten all four speech successes out of Eli, and he really doesn't seem guilty (of murder).  He has a plausible explanation for how he got the brooch, and the coveralls in the trunk are stitched with Hugo's initials.  Yet, whenever I accuse Hugo of murder, the captain gets upset with me.

I [looked up a walkthrough](http://lanoire.wikia.com/wiki/The_Golden_Butterfly) and discovered that I'm supposed to accuse Eli of the murder.

**What evidence proves that Eli, rather than Hugo, is guilty?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is that there is none.  The lack of hard evidence against both suspects is supposed to nag at you.  The captain *wants* you to accuse the pedophile, as he's the better one to put behind bars.

I can't reveal what is going on, though, without massive spoilers:

> Neither man murdered Diedre - they're both innocent.  In fact, most of the murders you investigate while on the Homicide desk are actually being committed by [Garrett Mason](http://lanoire.wikia.com/wiki/Garrett_Mason), a truth you'll eventually discover in the final case of the desk.  The flimsy evidence you have against the two men is actually part of Mason's plot.

Comment: Fair enough. I won't read the spoilers until I've gotten farther in the game.

Comment: @SteveV., get used to this nagging feeling that something isn't right - it's only going to get worse from here :)

Comment: @SteveV.: ... or just get into the mind set of the time, lock up Eli and get on with your life, all smug and content for your job well done. :)